# How to filter SQL results when the referenced table can be empty?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, where-clause, exists

I have a query which selects from different tables, then uses a WHERE clause to filter the items.
The clause looks like this:

```sql
WHERE allItems.NumID != (SELECT RelatedNumID FROM allRelated WHERE NumID = allItems.NumID)
```

This works fine when `allRelated` table isn't empty.
But when it's empty, I get 0 results from the query.

I have tried to use `NOT IN` instead of `!=`. It returns result when `allRelated` is empty, but doesn't filter the results when `allRelated` isn't empty:

```sql
WHERE allItems.NumID NOT IN (SELECT RelatedNumID FROM allRelated WHERE NumID = allItems.NumID)
```

I also tried to join the tables, but I get the same result as with `NOT IN`:

```sql
LEFT JOIN allRelated ON allItems.NumID = allRelated.NumID
WHERE allRelated.NumID IS NOT NULL
```

How should I write the query so that it works for both empty and non-empty `allRelated` table?

P.S. I'm using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM allRelated 
  WHERE allRelated.NumID = allItems.NumID
    AND allRelated.RelatedNumID = allItems.NumID
)
```

or, change the condition in the `WHERE` clause of the `LEFT` join to `IS NULL`:

```
LEFT JOIN allRelated 
ON allItems.NumID = allRelated.NumID AND allRelated.RelatedNumID = allItems.NumID
WHERE allRelated.NumID IS NULL
```

Comment: this returns the result when `allRelated` is empty, but it doesn't filter the results as before when `allRelated` isn't empty.

Comment: @user3132457 can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?

Comment: i played with this a little bit, and your suggested solution worked when i changed the condition to `WHERE allRelated.NumID = allItems.NumID`.

Comment: @user3132457 changed from what? This is what I do in my query.

Comment: oh sorry, changed to this: `WHERE allRelated.NumID != allItems.NumID`

Comment: @user3132457 this does not make sense with NOT EXISTS. Check your requirement and the results that you get again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240721/discussion-between-user3132457-and-forpas).